# How can I print exercise with ID in xsim?

Tags: xsim

I have some exercises with ID.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{xsim,pgffor}
\usepackage{needspace}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{runin}
{%
\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
\Needspace * {2\baselineskip}
\noindent
\textbf{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
\GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
\GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
\marginpar{%
\PropertyValue
\GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{+\PropertyValue}%
\,\IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
 {\XSIMtranslate{point}}
{\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
 }%
 }%
 }
 {}
\xsimsetup{
exercise/within=section ,
exercise/template=runin,
solution/template=runin,
solution/print = true,
exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise}.}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{exam}

\begin{document}
\chapter{AAA}
\section{BBB}
\collectexercises{exam}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q1]
  1
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  1
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q2]
  2
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  2
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q3]
  3
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  3
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q4]
  4
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q5]
  5
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q6]
  6
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q7]
  7
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q8]
  8
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q9]
  9
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[ID=q10]
  10
\end{exercise}
\printcollection{all exercises}
\section{Print with ID}
\printexercise{exercise}{q3}

\section{Answers}
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Now I want to print one (or some) exercise. I tried

```
\printexercise{exercise}{q3}
```

or

```
\printexercise{exercise}{q1,q3,q5}
```

But I can't get the result. How can I get it?

Comment: `\printexercise{exercise}{q1,q3,q5}` can't work. It doesn't even match the description of the `\printexercise`... you're missing that there are *two different types of id*: `id` and `ID`. `\XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{q3}}}` should work… (it would probably best to define a wrapper macro `\newcommand\insertexercise[1]{\XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{#1}}}}`)

Comment: @clemens I copied your code, but I didn't get the result. Is there a command in front of `\begin{document}`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: BTW your code is missing `\collectexercisesstop{exam}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried [...]
>
> ```
> \printexercise{exercise}{q1,q3,q5}
> ```

That actually doesn't make much sense as it doesn't follow the command description of `\printexercise` (p.19 of the current manual):

> - `\printexercise{<type>}{<id>}` 
>     Inserts the exercise of type `<type>` with the `id` `<id>`.

It is important to notice expects the `id` whereas in the question you tried to use the `ID` (p.10 of the current manual):

- `id = {<integer>}` 
  Holds the internal id of an exercise. Cannot be set by the user.
- `ID = {<text>}` 
  Holds the user id of an exercise if defined. Otherwise it is equal to `id`.

---

Here is a way that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[ID=foo]
  bla bla
\end{exercise}

\XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{foo}}}

\end{document}
```

or probably better

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\newcommand*\insertexercise[1]{%
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[ID=foo]
  bla bla
\end{exercise}

\insertexercise{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Suppose I have 10 exercises with ID=foo, when I type \insertexercise{foo}, I only get one exercise. How can I get enough 10 exercises?

Comment: @toandhsp each ID *must* be individual. (If assigning the same ID to several exercises doesn't throw an error when compiling then there is a bug in `xsim`.) It seems you want to insert exercises fitting certain tags, maybe something like this: https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/blob/master/examples/xsim.collections.tex

Comment: I cleared points, but when I compile, I still get points. How can I clear all points?

Comment: @toandhsp delete the aux file and compile from scratch.

Comment: @clements When I use class report with your file, the order of exercises didn't correct. How can I repair?

Comment: Great solution! Could you explain why you need \XSIMexpandcode? When I tried to make a command like \insertexerciseS{q1,q2,q3} using a for loop, nothing happened. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @MichielVanCouwenberghe It is needed so `\printexercise` sees the *result* (i.e. the id) of `\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{#1}` instead of seeing a macro which eventually expands to the id

Comment: @clemens Is that the reason why (with your definition of `\insertexercise`) the code `\makeatletter \@for\x:={id1,id2}\do{\insertexercise{\x}} \makeatother` does not work?

Comment: @MichielVanCouwenberghe a similar reason. Try `\do{\expandafter\insertexercise\expandafter{\x}`