# Properly defining problems and subproblems using the xsim package

Tags: exercises, xsim, examdesign

I am trying to use the `xsim` package to sort and order the previously given exams in a course (MAT-1001). For this to be viable I need the following equirements

- I should be able to request exam problems by ID, topic, or year.
- I want to be able to request both questions and subquestions.

I tried to do this with the code below, but I have never encountered such bizzare results in my life. The expected output is so far from what I would expect. The code in its entirety can be found below, but I want to step through it one problem at a time.

The following file is a sample file showing a few common exercises.

### exam.tex

```
\begin{question}[
  year=2017,semester=V,exam=O
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a,
  topic = integral
  ]
  Evaluate the following integrals
  \begin{tasks}(3)
    \task $\displaystyle \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi/2}} (x+1) \e^{x-1} dx$
    \task $\displaystyle \int \frac{a}{x^2 + a^2} dx$
    \task $\displaystyle \int \log x dx$.
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[
  year=2017,semester=V,exam=O
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-b,
  topic = limit
  ]
  Evaluate the following limits
  \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$
    \task $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{1 + x^2}$.
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[
  year=2017,semester=V,exam=O
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-c,
  topic = injective
  ]
  State the definition of an injective function and provle
  that the function $f \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\int_0^x
  e^{-s^2} dx$ is injective.
\end{question}

\begin{exercise}[year=2017,semester=H,topic={integral,limit,injective},exam=K,
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a}
    \item \insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-b}
    \item \insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-c}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

This leads me to my first two questions

- I want to tag the questions and use these tags, however the code above does not work. I am not able to filter out say every question with the topic `integral`.
- How can I put togheter questions to form an exercise (or exam problem)?

I tried to use the code

```
\newcommand*\insertexercise[1]{%
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{#1}}}%
}
```

From [How can I print exercise with ID in xsim?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383207/how-can-i-print-exercise-with-id-in-xsim). To insert the questions into the exercise:

```
\begin{exercise}[year=2017,semester=H,topic={complex,differential},exam=K,
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a}
    \item \insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-b}
    \item \insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-c}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

However that did not work. How can one properly do this? And how would this work when displaying solutions?

In the remainder of this question I post snippets of my MWE, sharing my frustrations over things that does not work as I would expect.

- The lines below fails to compile when uncommented, why?

  ```
  % \collectexercisestype{all}
  %   \input{exam.tex}
  % \collectexercisesstop{all}
  ```

I have already defined the file `exam.tex` The following code works however

```
\collectexercisestype{exercise-pool}{exercise}
  \input{exam.tex}
\collectexercisesstop{exercise-pool}

% Random exercise
\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \printrandomexercises[collection=exercise-pool]{2}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

- I would expect the code above to print the sole `Exercise` environment
  from `exam.tex` instead it prints nothing. Why?

The following code *does* print out subquestions. However, why does it only print out *one* no matter what number I input?

```
\collectexercises{subquestions}{subquestion}
  \input{exam.tex}
\collectexercisesstop{subquestions}

% Random subquestion
\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \printrandomexercises[collection=subquestions]{2}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

The following code I would expect to print out the `Exercise` environment from the file, alas it prints nothing

```
\insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1}
```

Similarly the following code prints nothing as well

```
\insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a}
```

In addition I can not print any of the collections as this gives me an `undefined item` error.

```
\section{All}

% \printcollection{all}

\section{Exercises}

% \printcollection{exercise-pool}

\section{Subquestions}

% \printcollection{subquestions}
```

---

The file `exam.tex` is defined at the start of the question

### main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{xsim}

% \xsimsetup{
%   exercise/name=,
%   solution/print=true,
%   solution/name=Solution,
% }

\DeclareExerciseTagging{year} % 1992, 2010, etc
\DeclareExerciseTagging{topic}
\DeclareExerciseTagging{semester} % V (Spring), H (Fall)
\DeclareExerciseTagging{exam} % O (ordinary), K (kont / re-sit exam), P (prøveeksamen)

\DeclareExerciseCollection{MAT-1001-Integrals}

\DeclareExerciseType{subquestion}{
  exercise-env = question ,
  solution-env = answer ,
  exercise-name = Question ,
  solution-name = Answer ,
  exercise-template = item ,
  solution-template = item
}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{title}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{named}
  {\subsection*{\GetExercisePropertyTF{title}{#1}{??}}}
  {}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{item}
  {\item}
  {}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = named
}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{all}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{exercise-pool}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{subquestions}

\newcommand{\problemfolder}{exam-problems}

\newcommand*\insertexercise[1]{%
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\GetExerciseIdForProperty{ID}{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

% The lines below fails to compile why?

% \collectexercisestype{all}
%   \input{exam.tex}
% \collectexercisesstop{all}

% Random subproblem or exercise
% \begin{exercise}[title=Random subproblem or exercise]
%   \begin{enumerate}
%     \item \printrandomexercises[collection=all]{2}
%   \end{enumerate}
% \end{exercise}

% Why does the \printrandomexercises{2} only print 1 instead of two exercises?
% Why does it print the subquestions instead of the exercise?

\collectexercisestype{exercise-pool}{exercise}
  \input{exam.tex}
\collectexercisesstop{exercise-pool}

% Random exercise
\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \printrandomexercises[collection=exercise-pool]{1}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

% Why does the code below print absolutely nothing?

\collectexercises{subquestions}{subquestion}
  \input{exam.tex}
\collectexercisesstop{subquestions}

% Random subquestion
\begin{exercise}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \printrandomexercises[collection=subquestions]{2}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}

% Why does the code below print nothing? Is it possible to nest \insertexercise?

Should print the first problem

\insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1}

% I can sort of understand why the code above does not work, but why
% can it not print subproblems either?

Should print the first subproblem (problem 1-a)

\insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a}

\section{All}

% \printcollection{all}

\section{Exercises}

% \printcollection{exercise-pool}

\section{Subquestions}

% \printcollection{subquestions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are so many questions here that it is hard to keep track. I decided to answer the basic problems in your code. This may also help with the other problems you had, I think.

1. The first problem is typos – there is a comma missing after `exam=0` in every of your `question`s (IMHO `xsim` should probably raise errors here but doesn't at the moment):

   ```
   \begin{question}[
     year=2017,semester=V,exam=O % <<<<< HERE
     ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-b,
     topic = limit
     ]
     ...
   \end{question}
   ```
2. Another problem is your use of `\insertexercise`. For one thing leave `ID=` away in the argument `\insertexercise{ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a}`. It should be the ID itself: `\insertexercise{MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a}`.
3. Another problem is that you have defined `\insertexercise` to only insert exercises of type `exercise` (`\printexercise{exercise}{...}`) but at the same time you are trying to insert exercises of type `subquestion` (as can be seen by the IDs you are using `\insertexercise` with).
4. A further problem is duplication of `\item` in `\item \insertexercise{...}`. You have defined the template of the subquestions to insert an `\item` themselves.

In a current version of `xsim` the second argument of `\printexercise` can either be the `id` *or* the `ID` which makes the definition of `\insertexercise` superfluous.

So, adding the missing commas and defining the exercise as follows:

```
\begin{exercise}[year=2017,semester=H,topic={integral,limit,injective},exam=K,
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \printexercise{subquestion}{MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a}
    \printexercise{subquestion}{MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-b}
    \printexercise{subquestion}{MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-c}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
```

Should give something reasonable. And indeed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tasks}

\providecommand*\e{e}

\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseTagging{year} % 1992, 2010, etc
\DeclareExerciseTagging{topic}
\DeclareExerciseTagging{semester} % V (Spring), H (Fall)
\DeclareExerciseTagging{exam} % O (ordinary), K (kont / re-sit exam), P (prøveeksamen)

\DeclareExerciseType{subquestion}{
  exercise-env = question ,
  solution-env = answer ,
  exercise-name = Question ,
  solution-name = Answer ,
  exercise-template = item ,
  solution-template = item
}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{title}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{named}
  {\subsection*{\GetExercisePropertyTF{title}{#1}{??}}}
  {}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{item}
  {\item}
  {}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = named
}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{all}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-exam.tex}
\begin{question}[
  year=2017,semester=V,exam=O,
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a,
  topic = integral
  ]
  Evaluate the following integrals
  \begin{tasks}(3)
    \task $\displaystyle \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi/2}} (x+1) \e^{x-1} dx$
    \task $\displaystyle \int \frac{a}{x^2 + a^2} dx$
    \task $\displaystyle \int \log x dx$.
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[
  year=2017,semester=V,exam=O,
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-b,
  topic = limit
  ]
  Evaluate the following limits
  \begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$
    \task $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{1 + x^2}$.
  \end{tasks}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[
  year=2017,semester=V,exam=O,
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-c,
  topic = injective
  ]
  State the definition of an injective function and provle
  that the function $f \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\int_0^x
  e^{-s^2} dx$ is injective.
\end{question}

\begin{exercise}[year=2017,semester=H,topic={integral,limit,injective},exam=K,
  ID=MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \printexercise{subquestion}{MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-a}
    \printexercise{subquestion}{MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-b}
    \printexercise{subquestion}{MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1-c}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\collectexercises{all}
  \input{\jobname-exam.tex}
\collectexercisesstop{all}

\printexercise{exercise}{MAT-1001-2017-V-H-Problem-1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you do something special to make your example above compile? Using *exactly* what you wrote produces no output. Both files in same folder etc. Any suggestions? I am a bit unsure how a `subquestion` should be typed...

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar the only thing you need is an up to date TeX distribution. I edited the answer to make the example self-contained ( using `filecontents` for the additional file with the exercises), so copy/paste/compiile works nicely on my system